# What's the safest way of doing a https POST with C++?

Tags: c++, post

I need a simple startup and may sound a little vague, but, What's the safest way of doing a https POST/GET with C++?
Has anyone experienced a good lib for it?

I'm in a middleware software project and is needed a simple https POST with JSON data structure, any pattern or article of your know?

Comment: On Linux, no boost. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by, "safe?"  What dev environment are you using?

Comment: Red Hat, running with Oracle.

Comment: As safe I mean, some lib, or pattern, hacker "proof", I know nothing is a hundred %.

Comment: [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html) seems like a nice alternative.

Comment: at first I minded ACE lib.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Did you experienced it? Heard about?

Comment: cpp-netlib is considered for inclusion in Boost, so it should be very good. Haven't used it my self through, but reading the documentation and examples it seems like a very good and complete HTTP client/server implementation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg POST it as an answer, probably won't have many, so I'll probably check yours. But I'll wait a little, thanks.

Comment: IIRC, if boost isn't an option, then cpp-netlib won't be an option, either.

Comment: Maybe `libcurl`... It is plain C, but I've used it from C++ without any problem.

Comment: @JeremySandell he said that it's a candidate for it. "Considered for inclusion", maybe I can branch it if it's free.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel My mistake, I was under the impression that it required other boost libraries. Either it did when I used it a few years ago or I simply recalled incorrectly. :D  Regardless, it worked quite well for my own needs.